# Angular 11 routing not working in AWS S3 and Cloudfront

Tags: angular, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront

I am trying to host my Angular 11 App using Cloudfront and S3. However, routing does not seem to be working.

**Ex: abc.cloudfront.net/home**
It ends up looking for the home file. Attached are some screenshots that maybe of help.
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: there should be something like "error file". put 'index.html' there and it should work

Comment: I had already added that in my Bucket, I have updated my screenshots. It seems like it is trying to look for the home file. Which essentially is the path.

Comment: This is correct behavior, as you are infact requesting an object named '/home'.

Comment: Why not handle this with Angular router?

Comment: because there is no angular, untill you've loaded the index.html and angular library and your app

Comment: I think the problem lies in my PWA angular app. I tried doing a production build locally and i see the same issue. It loads the app.component.html, but none of the components embedded inside of it get rendered. Any idea what I am doing wrong when I am building the app? All my routes etc work very well locally but fails in production.

Answer (score 0):

I finally resolved it, I had to change my build command to this: ng build --prod --aot=false --output-hashing=media --sourceMap=true --extract-css=false --buildOptimizer=false.

Comment: if it works for you - great; but these switches have nothing to do with the routing problem you described

Comment: That's what I just can't figure out. Should aot not be true? Going a bit mental as to why ng build --prod does not work, but this does.